# Why is $(\cos t,\sin t), t\in[0,2\pi)$ not a smooth, one-one parametrization of the entire unit circle?

Tags: differential-geometry

Why is $(\cos t,\sin t), t\in[0,2\pi)$ not a smooth, one-one parametrization of the entire unit circle?

Clearly, it is one-one. [I have left out $2\pi$ from the domain of $t$ for this purpose]

And, I am sure that it is smooth for all $t\in(0,2\pi)$, the only point that may cause trouble is $t=0$.

But, on wikipedia,

> A parametric curve $s:[0,1]\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}$ is said to be of class $C^k$, if $\frac {d^{k}s}{dt^{k}}$ exists and is continuous on $[0,1]$, where derivatives at the end-points $0,1\in[0,1]$ are taken to be one sided derivatives (i.e., at 0 from the right, and at 1 from the left).

So, according to this, wouldn't $(\cos t,\sin t)$ be differentiable at $0$?

I know there is a problem with this parametrization because I was asked to prove that there exists no smooth, one-one parametrization of the entire unit circle, I just can't figure out why this parametrization fails.

Thank you.

Comment: I would check what definition you are using in class, but notice that the wikipedia definition has a *compact* interval as its domain.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Ah, that could be an issue.

Comment: It's not derivable at left of $0$. Charts must be defined on open sets.

Comment: @Surb Yes, it isn't. But according the article on wikipedia, over a domain $[a,b]$, the derivative at $a$ will be taken only from the *right*.

Comment: You should give us the definiton of a **parametrization**. Is it a chart for a manifold?